# Show List in Struts2 view

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using struts2 as MVC framework,but i had an issue,my problem is in Action,I defined 
a model which called "Company",Its definition is as following:

```
class Company
{
  private String name;
  private String address;
  ...
  private List<Staff>staffs;
  ...
}

class Staff
{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   ....
}
```

The Action is as following

```
class Action
{
  private Company company;
  public String execute(){

  }
}
```

How to show the whole company and staff info in view(The view is JSP file) ?what i expected in UI is:

```
Company info
  company name                company address...
Staff 1 info
   staff name                 staff age...
Staff 2 info
   staff name                 staff age...
```

How to define the jsp file?even though company info could be shown by using OGNL,but how about staff info,As it is a List and its number is uncertain

Someone told me i could use iterator,but my requirement is:
Beside show the staff infomation in UI,I also hope to let the staff could be editable,e.g maybe i will define "form" as following

```
<s:form> 
    Company info: Company Name:<s:input name="company.name"/> Company Address:<s:input name="company.name"/> 
   Staff 1 info: .... 
   Staff 2 info: ... 
 <s:form>
```

Is it possible to define the staff info with "form" or "input"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point to elements of Lists or Maps specifying their index with the IteratorStatus object:

```
<s:property value="company.name"/>
<s:property value="company.address"/>

<s:iterator value="company.staffs" status="stat">

    <span>Staff <s:property value="%{#stat.index}" /> info: </span>

    <label>name: </label>
    <s:textfield name="company.staffs[%{#stat.index}].name" />

    <label>age: </label>
    <s:textfield name="company.staffs[%{#stat.index}].age" />

    <br/>

</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Yes,That's exactly what i expected,Thanks,By the way,Can you recommend any tutorial of how to use OGNL in such case?e.g in List,Map or any other commonly used java data structure

Comment: @Chailie On the wiki there's some [examples](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/iterator-tag-examples.html), but they are scarce ;)

Comment: Sorry @Chailie , no. But they're always the same... `[%{#stat.index}]` for numeric indexes (Lists), `['%{#stat.index}']` for String keys (Maps). Feel free to dig into my OGNL and Struts2 tagged question (My profile -> tags -> click on the tag -> browse the answers), maybe you'll find something interesting about this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Struts2 [Iterator tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator.html) to iterator over the list and show all information on your JSP page

Iterator will iterate over a value. An iterable value can be any of: `java.util.Collection, java.util.Iterator`

For more details refer to Iterator [tag example](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/iterator-tag-examples.html).

Answer (score 1):

To get the company name and address just do

```
 <s:property value="company.name"/>
 <s:property value="company.address"/>
```

And to get list of staffs use struts iterator tag

```
<s:iterator value="company.staffs" status="stat">
   Staff <s:property value="%{#stat.index}" /> 
      <s:property value="name" />  &nbsp;  <s:property value="age" />
      </br>

</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Beside show the staff infomation in UI,I also hope to let the staff could be editable,e.g
maybe i will define "form" as following
`<s:form>
Company info:
 Company Name:<s:input name="company.name"/> Company Address:<s:input name="company.name"/>
Staff 1 info:
 ....

Staff 2 info:
 ...
  
<s:form>`
Is it possible to define the staff info with "form" or "input"?

Comment: Yes you can do this by using <s:textfield name="" /> tag.